# how set Header in a process in Apache Camel

Tags: json, rest, http-headers

I want to change my header content-type from text/html to application/json.
my current header is : {CamelHttpMethod=POST,, CONTENT_TYPE=application/json}

and I want to  remove  Content-Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8 by setting header in a process like:

```
   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
String mainBody = exchange.getIn().getBody().toString();

JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(mainBody));
JsonObject body = reader.readObject();     
reader.close();
exchange.getIn().setHeaders(exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("application/json"));
/System.out.println("your header" + exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
exchange.getIn().setBody(body.getJsonObject("API3"));
 }
```

}

is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're conflating the [Exchange](http://camel.apache.org/exchange.html) header with an HTTP response header. Moreover, while it might be possible to set RESTful properties within the scope of a Processor IMHO you should only use a Processor for business logic germane to the Exchange message content and use something like Camel's [REST DSL](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html) to handle the REST headers.

Here is an example of what that might look like:

```
    rest().path("/dummy")
          .get()
          .route()
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, simple("200"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("application/json"))
          .to("bean:" + DUMMY_BEAN_NAME);
```